# Hazelcast cluster not available on Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, netflix-eureka

I had a problem configuring simple Hazelcast cluster for existing Eureka client. 
My application is simple Java SpringBoot application with Eureka discovery enabled, it is properly available for Eureka, however Hazelcast cluster is not.

This is my configuration:

hazelcast.xml

```
<hazelcast
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.9.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.jmx">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.http.healthcheck.enabled">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.rest.enabled">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.diagnostics.enabled">true</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.diagnostics.metric.level">info</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.name">hazelcast-cluster</property>
</properties>

<group>
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <password>xx</password>
</group>

<instance-name>hazelcast-cluster</instance-name>

<network>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false"/>
        <tcp-ip enabled="false"/>
        <aws enabled="false"/>
        <discovery-strategies>
            <discovery-strategy class="com.hazelcast.eureka.one.EurekaOneDiscoveryStrategy" enabled="true">
                <properties>
                    <property name="self-registration">true</property>
                    <property name="namespace">hazelcast</property>
                </properties>
            </discovery-strategy>
        </discovery-strategies>
    </join>
</network>

maps....

</hazelcast>
```

Spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration ( exclude = { WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class } )
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableEurekaClient
public class HazelcastClusterApplication {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( HazelcastClusterApplication.class, args );
    }  
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class HazelcastInstanceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(Config config, EurekaClient eurekaClient) { 
        EurekaOneDiscoveryStrategyFactory.setEurekaClient( eurekaClient );
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public Config config() {    
        Config config = new ClasspathXmlConfig( "hazelcast.xml" );
        return config;
    }
}
```

bootstrap.yml

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8011/eureka/
    register-with-eureka: true

spring:
  mvc:
    favicon:
      enabled: false
  application:
    name: cache-server
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: config-server
      failFast: false
      retry:
        initialInterval: 10000
        maxInterval: 60000
        maxAttempts: 12
        multiplier: 10.1
  config:
    name: application.*, ${spring.application.name}*.*
server:
  port: 7990
```

Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-eureka-one</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

After running, 'cache-server' application is available on Eureka, however I guess also 'hazelcast-cluster' should be available, but it is not. Or my assumption is wrong?

Startup logs:

```
INFO 17628 --- [           main] c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     : [10.230.115.128]:5701 [xxxx] [3.11] Waiting for registration with Eureka...
INFO 17628 --- [           main] c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     : [10.230.115.128]:5701 [xxxx] [3.11] Waiting for registration with Eureka...
INFO 17628 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_CACHE-SERVER/pc_data:cache-server:7990: registering service...
INFO 17628 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_CACHE-SERVER/pc_data:cache-server:7990 - registration status: 204
INFO 17628 --- [           main] c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     : [10.230.115.128]:5701 [xxxx] [3.11] Waiting for registration with Eureka...
DEBUG 17628 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner       : [10.230.115.128]:5701 [xxxx] [3.11] This node will assume master role since no possible member where connected to.
DEBUG 17628 --- [           main] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [10.230.115.128]:5701 [xxxx] [3.11] Setting master address to [10.230.115.128]:5701
DEBUG 17628 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MembershipManager     : [10.230.115.128]:5701 [xxxx] [3.11] Local member list join version is set to 1
DEBUG 17628 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner       : [10.230.115.128]:5701 [xxxx] [3.11] PostJoin master: [10.230.115.128]:5701, isMaster: true
INFO 17628 --- [           main] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [10.230.115.128]:5701 [xxxx] [3.11] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [10.230.115.128]:5701 - f6ed031e-5740-4daa-b583-5b91d98816c2 this
]
```

And then my cache-server application is available on Eureka, but not hazelcast-cluster as I guess it should.

Hazelcast client service logs (cutted):

```
2018-12-11 09:48:01.673  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient     : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] A non-empty group password is configured for the Hazelcast client. Starting with Hazelcast version 3.11, clients with the same group name, but with different group passwords (that do not use authentication) will be accepted to a cluster. The group password configuration will be removed completely in a future release.
2018-12-11 09:48:01.700  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] HazelcastClient 3.11 (20181023 - 1500bbb) is STARTING
2018-12-11 09:48:03.233  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2018-12-11 09:48:03.249  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2018-12-11 09:48:03.264  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-12-11 09:48:03.266  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-12-11 09:48:03.267  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2018-12-11 09:48:03.267  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2018-12-11 09:48:03.417  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2018-12-11 09:48:03.421  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2018-12-11 09:48:03.421  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2018-12-11 09:48:03.422  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2018-12-11 09:48:03.422  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2018-12-11 09:48:03.423  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2018-12-11 09:48:03.424  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2018-12-11 09:48:03.424  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2018-12-11 09:48:03.426  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2018-12-11 09:48:03.426  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 5
2018-12-11 09:48:03.426  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2018-12-11 09:48:03.442  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1544518083442 with initial instances count: 3
2018-12-11 09:48:03.488  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Waiting for registration with Eureka...
2018-12-11 09:48:08.468  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SECURITY-SERVICE/GPLPLW2002.gft.com:security-service:8035 - Re-registering apps/SECURITY-SERVICE
2018-12-11 09:48:08.468  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SECURITY-SERVICE/GPLPLW2002.gft.com:security-service:8035: registering service...
2018-12-11 09:48:08.499  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Waiting for registration with Eureka...
2018-12-11 09:48:08.530  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SECURITY-SERVICE/GPLPLW2002.gft.com:security-service:8035 - registration status: 204
2018-12-11 09:48:13.500  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Waiting for registration with Eureka...
2018-12-11 09:48:18.503  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Waiting for registration with Eureka...
2018-12-11 09:48:23.512  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Waiting for registration with Eureka...
2018-12-11 09:48:28.513  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Waiting for registration with Eureka...
2018-12-11 09:48:33.515  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Waiting for registration with Eureka...
2018-12-11 09:48:33.557  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.h.client.spi.ClientInvocationService   : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Running with 2 response threads
2018-12-11 09:48:33.742  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] HazelcastClient 3.11 (20181023 - 1500bbb) is STARTED
2018-12-11 09:48:33.772 DEBUG [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.h.i.networking.nio.NioNetworking       : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 1 input threads and 1 output threads
2018-12-11 09:48:33.774 DEBUG [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] c.h.i.networking.nio.NioNetworking       : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] IO threads selector mode is SELECT
2018-12-11 09:48:33.818  WARN [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [ient_0.cluster-] c.h.c.c.ClientConnectionManager          : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 3000 ms later, attempt 1 of 2.
2018-12-11 09:48:36.822  WARN [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [ient_0.cluster-] c.h.c.c.ClientConnectionManager          : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Unable to get alive cluster connection, attempt 2 of 2.
2018-12-11 09:48:36.824  WARN [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [ient_0.cluster-] c.h.c.c.ClientConnectionManager          : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Could not connect to cluster, shutting down the client. Unable to connect to any address! The following addresses were tried: []
2018-12-11 09:48:36.828  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [clientShutdown-] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] HazelcastClient 3.11 (20181023 - 1500bbb) is SHUTTING_DOWN
2018-12-11 09:48:36.839  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [clientShutdown-] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2018-12-11 09:48:36.843  INFO [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [clientShutdown-] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
2018-12-11 09:48:36.844  WARN [security-service,,,] 21496 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: o.....org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource 
.......
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [xxxx/hazelcast/HazelcastClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address! The following addresses were tried: []
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 150 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address! The following addresses were tried: []
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 163 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address! The following addresses were tried: []
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnector.connectToClusterInternal(ClusterConnector.java:206)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnector.access$400(ClusterConnector.java:56)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnector$2.call(ClusterConnector.java:215)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnector$2.call(ClusterConnector.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
```

What is wrong with my configuration, is this a server problem or client?

Client configuration:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance( EurekaClient eurekaClient, GroupConfig groupConfig ) {

    EurekaOneDiscoveryStrategyFactory.setEurekaClient( eurekaClient );

    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.setGroupConfig( groupConfig );
    config.setProperty( "hazelcast.discovery.enabled", "true" );

    DiscoveryStrategyConfig discoveryStrategyConfig = new DiscoveryStrategyConfig( new EurekaOneDiscoveryStrategyFactory() );
    discoveryStrategyConfig.addProperty( "use-classpath-eureka-client-props", "false" );
    discoveryStrategyConfig.addProperty( "self-registration", "false" );

    DiscoveryConfig discoveryConfig = new DiscoveryConfig();
    discoveryConfig.addDiscoveryStrategyConfig( discoveryStrategyConfig );
    config.getNetworkConfig().setDiscoveryConfig( discoveryConfig );

    return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient( config );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the same EurekaClient for you app discovery (port 7990) and your Hazelcast discovery (port 5701). For more information, read the related [GH issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-eureka/issues/1).

You can solve it in two ways:

- Use the property `use-metadata-for-host-and-port` as described [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-eureka#configuring-eureka-discovery-for-hazelcast-cluster-members)
- Use separate Eureka Client and ports for your app and Hazelcast

EDIT: The `use-metadata-for-host-and-port` will be released in `hazelcast-eureka:1.0.3` soon. I've also prepared [Hazelcast Eureka Code Sample](https://github.com/leszko/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/eureka/hazelcast-integration/eureka/springboot-embedded).

Comment: I think that it helps me to understand the problem, I successfully registered Hazelcast cluster in Eureka. The problem is now that I cannot reach this cluster from Eureka Client application (with exisitng, autowired EurekaClient). Could you please help me? I updated post description with HazelcastInstance configuration for client project, groupConfig is properly injected. Hazelcast client tries to connect to local port instead of eureka: hz.client_0 [xxxx] [3.11] Trying to connect to [127.0.0.1]:5702 as owner member

Comment: I think that in the client you also need to specify `namespace` (set it to `hazelcast` as you did in the Hazelcast member).

Comment: I've edited my answer, please have a look. Also, I've added Code Sample which will clarify how to use Hazelcast Eureka Plugin.

Comment: @RafałLeszko thanks, adding `use-metadata-for-host-and-port` helped me to register hazelcast members on PCF using PCF Register Service

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the example configs in [Eureka plugin repo](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-eureka) and also the [code sample with Eureka](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/springboot-eureka-partition-groups)? I see there are some differences in the configs with yours. Please check and let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to follow it, however there are lack of examples with reusing exisiting EurekaClient object. To be fair I don't know what should I expect doing hazelcast server registration, should it be available on Eureka like normal Spring Boot app? Second link has a bit overcomplicated solution, as it is using partition groups and I need simply one cluster instance.